# What is Project->ProjectExtensions->VisualStudio->UserProperties node for in the .vcxproj file?

Tags: visual-studio

I did something in MSVS 2010 which modified a .vcxproj file by adding this:

```
<Project>
...
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <UserProperties RESOURCE_FILE="projectName.RC" />
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

I'm not sure why it added it or when it added it, just that it was added and my manager want's to know why and what it's for.  This code base is probably around 20 years old and it was never there before.

Any ideas why it would just appear like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MS Developer website:

> Allows MSBuild project files to contain non-MSBuild information.
>   Anything inside of a ProjectExtensions element will be ignored by
>   MSBuild.

Not a definitive answer, but it does shed light on its impact to your project file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycwcwzs7.aspx

Comment: Interesting.  Still not sure about what it is.  I had already removed it with no impact on the build, which is what is expected based on this information.  Thanks for the answer.